# Text not expanding horizontally SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, newline, hstack, swiftui-text

Fetching text from JSON API all is working fine however text is not taking full space horizontally instead wrapping up after every item:

```
HStack(alignment: .top){
    HStack{
        Text("Sample Type :")
            .font(.system(size: 12))
            .padding(.leading,18)
        
    }
    HStack(spacing: 4){
        ForEach(card.sampleType.indices){raw in
            Text("\(raw+1)." + "\(card.sampleType[raw].sampleName)")
                .font(.system(size:12))
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        }
    }
}.foregroundColor(.blue)
```

sampleName is coming from nested array. I need the numbering also so concatenated as shown in code. I tried all possible combo as suggested in SO or else where but nothing working see pic.

I want like this :

```
Sample Type : 1.Fluoride Plasma - F 2.EDTA Whole Blood 3.Serum 4. Fluoride 
              Plasma - F
```

Suggestions..[image: sampleName]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps you:

```
HStack(alignment: .top) {
    HStack() {
        Text("Sample Type :")
            .font(.system(size: 12))
            .padding(.leading, 18)
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack() {
                ForEach(card.sampleType.indices){raw in
                    Text("\(raw+1)." + "\(card.sampleType[raw].sampleName)")
                        .font(.system(size: 12))
                        .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}.foregroundColor(.blue)
```

Comment: Thanks @stosha tried it already, text goes out of visible screen can't use scrollview

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behaviour of the `Text` view. If you want to achieve what you want you can put everything into one single `Text`. You would need to reduce your output into one single `String`.

```
var body: some View {
    HStack(alignment: .top){
        Text("Sample Type :")
            .font(.system(size: 12))
            .padding(.leading,18)
        
        Text(getNormalized())
            .font(.system(size: 12))
            .padding()
    }.foregroundColor(.blue)
}

func getNormalized() -> String{
    var result = ""
    
    for (index, card) in workoutTexts.enumerated(){
        result += "\(index+1)." + "\(card.sampleType[index].sampleName) "
    }
    
    return result
}
```